# What does the / sign means in the signature of numpy functions like sqrt?

Tags: python, numpy

What does the / sign means in the signature of numpy functions? The / sign appears between the positional and keword arguments.

For example:

```
sqrt(x, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj])
power(x1, x2, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj])
```

[Online documentation of numpy.sqrt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html) -- [and numpy.power functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html#numpy.power).